# AIML editor for Ubuntu to Develop Chatbots

Tags: text-editor

I am starting to learn AIML with python. I did do a little research about the AIML, python and its supporting versions for AIML. I have python 2.7.12 I am totally new to AIML, python and Ubuntu. I am not sure whether this combination is a good platform to develop chatbots. When I was looking for AIML editors I found so many dead links and only web-based editor(pandorabots.com).

Can you suggest some decent local editor for AIML?